# How to keep roadnetwork attributes by cutting it to a service area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network, vector-layer, road, service-area

I extracted a road network including attributes (e.g., categorization of different types of highways) using QuickOSM.
My **goal** is to cut this original road network to a 50km drivable radius from a certain starting point. This can be nicely done with the "service area" tool in QGIS. However, when I use that tool, all the attributes get deleted from the resulting service area layer. Unfortunately, I also couldn't find a tool to cut the original road network according to the newly created service area layer.
**Do you know how I could cut my original road network to the 50km service area network without loosing its attribute data?**

Comment: Buffer the 50 km area network by about 5 m, then clip the original network, _tadaaaa_

Comment: Or join attributes, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428931/88814